# No "if DEBUG" needed anymore for previews?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, preview

I've just created a new SwiftUI project with Xcode 11.3 and it doesn't wrap the preview code in a conditional "if DEBUG" as the beta versions used to do. Hence I'm wondering whether the compiler removes the preview code anyway for production compilation. Does anybody know?

Here's the currently generated source code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: See [Resolved Issues](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes)

Comment: @Asperi: Okay, it says:"The #if/#endif compiler conditionals surrounding PreviewProvider types have been removed from SwiftUI templates. PreviewProviders aren’t properly removed from built products when archived.". But what does that mean exactly? The previews remain in productive builds, because removal process is not working?